# Generate a random number which is not there in a table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for generating a random number which the generated number is not there on another table.

For Example: If a table called `randomNums` having the values `10,20,30,40,50`.

I like to generate a number apart from the above values.

I tried the following query.

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*100) AS rn
)
SELECT rn FROM CTE
WHERE rn NOT IN (SELECT num FROM randomNums);
```

But sometimes this query returns nothing.
Because that time it generates the number which is there in the table `randomNums`.

How to solve this issue?

**[Fiddle for reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d7ce21/1)**

Comment: You are multiplying by 100. Does these mean that you have range from 0 to 100?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yet another option, I've always liked `NEWID()` for random ordering, and cross joins create many rows very efficiently:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 1)
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT TOP 100 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.n) n
               FROM cte a,cte b,cte c,cte d, cte e, cte f, cte g)
SELECT TOP 1 n
FROM cte2 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM randomNums b
                  WHERE a.n = b.num)
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/faeec/9/0)

Comment: You get my vote for the only solution that works and isn't a nasty loop.

Comment: This solution does not work as efficiently if you need a random number between (say) 1 and 1 million, however, as it requires ordering 1 million numbers every time. For large, sparse ranges the iterative sampling method can win on time.

Comment: That's true, the fastest way to do this on a large scale is to use a properly indexed numbers table.

Comment: What "proper index" would give you fast random numbers? Even a numbers table isn't faster if you have to do `ORDER BY NEWID()`. Unless you mean we lay down the random sequence once and for all -- which I suppose *would* work, as long as you're careful about how you use your random sequence :-)

Comment: Yes, you can build the random number sequence, it all depends on usage, the above is well-suited to the task at hand.  We don't know if they are adding random numbers to the table or consistently choosing them for another purpose and always excluding a subset, if not adding to the exclusion table then a pre-built list wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use a `WHILE` loop then you might look into this solution which employs a recursive `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*100) AS rn  

    UNION ALL

    SELECT s.rn 
    FROM (
       SELECT rn      
       FROM CTE 
       WHERE rn NOT IN (SELECT num FROM randomNums)                         
       ) t
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*100) AS rn) AS s
    WHERE t.rn IS NULL

)
SELECT rn
FROM CTE
```

**EDIT:**

As stated in comments below the above does not work: If the first generated number (from the `CTE` anchor member) is a number *already present* in `randomNums`, then the `CROSS JOIN` of the recursive member will return `NULL`, hence the number from the anchor member will be returned.

Here is a different version, based on the same idea of using a recursive `CTE`, that works:

```
DECLARE @maxAttempts INT = 100

;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*100) AS rn,  
          1 AS i 

   UNION ALL

   SELECT FLOOR(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))*100) AS rn, i = i + 1
   FROM CTE AS c
   INNER JOIN randomNums AS r ON c.rn = r.num   
   WHERE (i = i) AND (i < @maxAttempts) 
)
SELECT TOP 1 rn
FROM CTE
ORDER BY i DESC
```

Here, the anchor member of the `CTE` firstly generates a random number. If this number is already present in `randomNums` the `INNER JOIN` of the recursive member will succeed, hence yet another random number will be generated. Otherwise, the `INNER JOIN` will fail and the recursion will terminate.

A couple of things more to note:

- `i` variable is used to record the number of attempts made to generate a *'unique'* random number.
- The value of `i` is used in the `INNER JOIN` operation of the recursive member so as to join with the random value of the *immediately preceding* recursion **only**.
- Since repetitive calls of [`RAND()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) with the same seed value return the same results, we have to use `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` as the seed of `RAND()`.
- `@maxAttempts` can optionally be used to specify the maximum number of attempts made in order to generate a 'unique' random number.

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1038ec/5)

Comment: And here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/95a49/1) to prove this doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidG Indeed it does not work. `CROSS JOIN` will fail if the first generated number is contained in `randomNums`.

Answer (score 0):

**Query**

```
declare @RandomNums table (Num int);
insert into @RandomNums values (10),(20),(30),(40),(50),(60),(70),(80),(90);

-- Make a table of AvailableNumbers

with N as 
(
    select n from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(n)    
),
AvailableNumbers as 
(      
    select -- top 97 -- limit as you need
        row_number() over(order by (select 1)) as Number
    from 
        N n1, N n2 --, N n3, N n4, N n5, N n6 -- multiply as you need
),

-- Find which of AvailableNumbers is Vacant

VacantNumbers as
(
    select
        OrdinalNumber = row_number() over(order by an.Number) ,
        an.Number
    from
        AvailableNumbers an 
        left join @RandomNums rn on rn.Num = an.number
    where
        rn.Num is null
)

-- select rundom VacantNumber by its OrdinalNumber in VacantNumbers

select
    Number
from
    VacantNumbers
where
    OrdinalNumber = floor(rand()*(select count(*) from VacantNumbers) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to create an unique index on num value for table randomNums. Then in your code catch the possible error if duplicated key is generated, and in that case choose another number and re-try.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
declare @n as int

while @n is null and (select COUNT(*) from randomNums) < 100
Begin

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*100) AS rn
)
SELECT @n = rn FROM CTE
WHERE rn NOT IN (SELECT num FROM randomNums);

End

select @n
```

It would only be advisable to use this approach, if the number of exclusions is relatively small.

Comment: Try it and see if it does. It depends on how big your list of exclusions is of course. You could always add a limit control just in case

Comment: In practice, this should only run forever if the table contains all numbers from 1 to 100 (that is, it can't possibly generate a valid number), and a check should be added for this. Even so, performance will decrease with every number added. If this is a concern, another approach is to select from the holes in the table instead (this is @lobodava's answer). Which method works better depends on how many numbers you actually have and what the range is.