# How to generate random number that doesn't exist in other table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to create a temp table where TBL_1.RANDOM1 does not exist in TBL_2.RANDOM2. It works if RANDOM2 has no data but once a value is inserted, my code populates NULLS.

I've searched for a while and found one piece of code and thought it worked until some data was added to the column that I didn't want to duplicate.

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, MAX(COL2) AS COL2, MAX(COL3) AS COL3, (
    SELECT DISTINCT 'AUTOCT' 
                    + CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 899999) + 100000 AS VARCHAR(15)) AS RANDOM1
    WHERE RANDOM1 NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT RANDOM2
            FROM TBL_2
            WHERE RANDOM2 LIKE 'AUTOCT%'
            )
    ) AS RANDOM1, COUNT(COL5) AS COL5, SUM(COL6) AS COL6
INTO ##TEMP1
FROM TBL_1
```

Comment: Do you mean [`RAND()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610(v=sql.120).aspx)?

Comment: I don't see how the code you have pasted above will run at all. `COL1` is in the select list, but not in a `GROUP BY`. The `RANDOM1` in the where clause of the subquery refers to `TBL_1.RANDOM1` which doesn't make sense, because you want to check whether the new values exist already or not, correct? And again, `TBL_1.RANDOM1` is not in a `GROUP BY`. Is this for Microsoft SQL Server? By the way, global temp tables are almost always the wrong choice.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500029/generate-a-random-number-which-is-not-there-in-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Sorry! I forgot the group by statement. May I ask why I shouldn't use temp tables? I'm relatively new to SQL and programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I proper understood you then try to get random number by using [`RAND()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610(v=sql.120).aspx) function(if you use SQL Server 2005 or higher). For example:

```
DECLARE @Random INT
DECLARE @Upper INT = 1
DECLARE @Lower INT = 999
DECLARE @RandomField  VARCHAR(10)

SET @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)
SET @RandomField  = 'AUTOCT' + CAST(@Random as varchar(5))

IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from TBL_2 where RANDOM2 = @RandomField)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TBL_1 (RANDOM1) VALUES (@RandomField)
END
```

Comment: I'll give this a try and see how it works. How would this work if I have multiple rows? Would I have to use a WHILE statement?

Comment: Thanks MegaTron. This did the trick! I added a while loop because I had multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 "`SELECT DISTINCT`" statements in there.  A good rule of thumb is that if you're joining on tables and writing distincts you can probably find a better way.

I would do something like:

```
SELECT random1 
FROM table1
EXCEPT 
SELECT random2
FROM table2
```

Take those results and then get to your final result.

Comment: Would this work if I am populating a random number each time the code runs?

Comment: Also, I am not pulling a random number from TBL1, that is where it will be stored. Does this change anything?

Comment: This didn't seem to work properly. It populated the same random number for each row. I have four rows and would need each to generate a random number.